# Dropdown default value is displayed using Angular 2/4

Tags: javascript, angular

```
 <div *ngFor="let lib of library">
  <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="lib.item"></div>
<div>
 <md-select [(ngModel)]="lib.title">
    <md-option *ngFor="let book of books" [value]="book._id">{{book.bookname}}
    <md-option>
    </md-select>
</div>
</div>
```

In my controller I have

```
  books=[
        {_id: 1, bookname:'first book'},
        {_id: 2, bookname:'second book'},
        {_id: 3, bookname:'third book'}
      ]
```

Interface is

```
   export interface Ixyz{
         _id: string;
         item: string;
         title: ICat;
      }
```

so when I push something like

```
      var add:Ixyz={
          _id: '',
          item:'',
          title: 2
        }
```

I want to be able to have default value in the dropdown. I know how to find value using `ngModel`. But `ngModel` is being used for something different.
When I push new value using title=2 it doesnt show on dropdown because title: ICat  is referencing another interface.

Comment: Can you please explain why `[(ngModel)]` can't be used? If you're displaying a default value, but the value is not actually being populated into the `ngModel`, then the behaviour may be misleading

Comment: Just added the code why I cant use ngModel to display the default value

Comment: That doesn't really explain why, can't you just iterate the values of `library`, and set the `item` value on each of them?

Comment: why not u are using reactive form?

Comment: Issue is when adding a new record. I get empty fields but want to display default value at that time.

Comment: @UnluckyAj this was already developed so just trying to add few new features

Comment: When you add the new record, set the default value

Comment: @user184994 yes that is the problem I am having how to setup the default value

Comment: Set it on the object that your pushing into `library`? Can you add the code where you add a new record please?

Comment: Let me add the model that will make more sense

Comment: Dont worry about adding the model, if you're having issues when you add a new record, can you show us the function where you add a new record please?

Comment: Ok see in model title is refrencing another Interface because of that when i push new record it doesn't show on the dropdown have to manually do it

Comment: If you make books an observable and use async pipe for the dropdown menu, when new record is added to the observable, you will get the new list and default value would display correctly rather than empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add a new item into the array, just do:

```
var add:Ixyz={
    _id: '',
    item:'',
    title: this.books[1]
}
```

This will provide a default value that should match populate the dropdown.